# how to replace rosbuild_link_boost() with the catkin macro

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert a rosbuild package([DSP-3000 package source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers/tree/Indigo)) to catkin package.

Currently on section 1.3 step 5 of [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild).

In the old package (rosbuild), the DSP-3000/CMakeLists.txt has the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

include_directories(cereal_port/include)
rosbuild_add_executable(dsp3000 src/dsp3000.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dsp3000 cereal_port)
rosbuild_link_boost(dsp3000 thread)

add_subdirectory(cereal_port)
```

The tutorial said `If rosbuild macros were used, switch from rosbuild macros to the underlying CMake commands`. so, I replaced all the rosbuild macros with catkin macros, shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)


find_package()
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

include_directories(cereal_port/include)
add_executable(dsp3000 src/dsp3000.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dsp3000 cereal_port)


add_subdirectory(cereal_port)
```

Now the next step is to `Declare how your targets (C++ binaries) shall be installed`. In my  case, Can anyone tell me what do I need to add in my DSP-3000/CMakeLists.txt to complete this step?

Also, can anyone check if I did the rosbuild to catkin conversion correctly for this file?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290768/how-to-replace-rosbuild_link_boost()-with-the-catkin-macro/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to [catkin documentation: C++ system library dependencies](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html). Then follow through to [catkin documentation: Building and installing C++ executables](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_executables.html#building-executables-2).

On both pages, `Boost` is used as an example.

---

Edit: I'm slightly confused. Looking at the `master` branch of [ros-drivers/kvh_drivers](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers) it already appears to be a Catkin package (`CMakeLists.txt` [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers/blob/2a5c173939a16fe6f4151e0580ade75114bf975c/CMakeLists.txt) and `package.xml` [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers/blob/2a5c173939a16fe6f4151e0580ade75114bf975c/package.xml)). It was converted in [ros-drivers/kvh_drivers#2](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers/pull/2).

Do you have any specific reason to want to use the `indigo` branch? I'm not sure why that is still there, as it seems to have lagged behind `master` quite a bit.

---

Edit2: I've opened [ros-drivers/kvh_drivers#6](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers/issues/6) to ask the maintainer(s) what the status of the `Indigo` branch is.

---

Edit3:

> You are right, I was able to build it successfully, then I ran `rosrun kvh dsp3000` and it gave me an error shown in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoCljaUshwh1y3LuPKHEKm1NDDGCClfW/view?usp=sharing)

that would seem to be a different issue. Let's not mix them.

If your current question was answered, please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-10**:
Thank you so much for the help, The robot that I am working on uses ubuntu 14.04 Indigo. Therefore, I am trying to download the Indigo release of kvh_drivers.

Also, The master branch is for kinetic version and I tried to build and run it but it gave me an error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-10**:
What makes you think it's "for Kinetic"?

I just built it in an Indigo Docker container and it seems to build fine.

As I don't have the hw, I can't run it, but I would expect it to just work.

What 'error' did it give you?

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-10**:
[this link](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/700bc9bfc8964138798fa43ea0f0ef1503d7756e/kinetic/distribution.yaml#L4433)
You are right, I was able to build it successfully, then I ran `rosrun kvh dsp3000` and it gave me an error shown in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoCljaUshwh1y3LuPKHEKm1NDDGCClfW/view?usp=sharing)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-10**:
That just tells you the package has been released into Kinetic. It doesn't mean it only works on Kinetic.

Please just try to build the `master` branch on Indigo. It should work.

Be sure to update the launch file with the correct port before you try to start it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-10**:
And please also make sure to use the correct procedure for building pkgs from source. See #q252478 for an example workflow if needed.

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-10**:
Thank you.